# Expected value of the following expression

Tags: self-study, expected-value, negative-binomial-distribution

I need to find the expected value of $\frac{\sum x_i}{n-\sum x_i},\ i=1, 2, \ldots, n$, where the $x_i$'s are negative binomial $NB(1, \theta)$.

Edit: More context about the problem:

I looked for the MLE for $\theta$ using $x_i$'s, iid negative binomial variables to estimate $\theta$ which gave me $\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$. I then needed to find the MLE for $\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$. Using the invariance property of MLEs, I got  $\frac{\sum x_i}{n-\sum x_i}$.

Now I need to show if this estimator is unbiased for $\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$. Is there a better way than taking the expectation?

Comment: How do you propose to deal with the nonzero probability that this expression will be undefined when all the $x_i=1$?  (Ordinarily, that makes the expectation undefined, too.)

Comment: Hint: The expression takes on value $\frac{k}{n-k}$ with probability $\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$, but as Huber points out, that makes the expected value be unbounded. You sure that the denominator does not have a $n+1-\sum x_i$ term? It cancels out very conveniently with the $n-k+1$ term in $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: I added more details to the problem. I basically need the expectation to prove unbiasedness of my estimator. Can I do this without having to evaluate the given expectation?

Comment: I think I made a mistake, the xi's are actually negative binomial also.

Comment: Ok. So I edited the mistake. My problem remains. I need to see if the estimator is unbiased and I don't know how to evaluate that expectation.

Comment: Your problem remains: because there is positive probability that your estimator is undefined, *it has no expectation.*  In that sense it cannot possibly be unbiased.

Comment: @whuber Actually,the duplicate was posted 11 hours later than this question. But i agree that the duplicate is better stated.

Comment: @Dilip Yes--after considering the potential effects of both decisions--close this or close the other--as well as the potential effects of merging the threads, it seemed this was the best course of action.